# Ergodicity property for continuous-time Harris positive Markov process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

The following theorem is Theorem 13.3.3 of Meyn and Tweedie's *Markov Chains and Stochastic Stability* on page 328

> Theorem 13.3.3. If $\Phi$ is positive Harris and aperiodic, then for every initial distribution $\lambda$
>   $$||\int\lambda(dx)P^n(x,\cdot)-\pi||\to 0,n\to\infty$$
>   where $\pi$ is invariant for $P$.

My question:

For the continuous-time positive Harris Markov process, does the theorem also true? or is there any similar property? As the book restricts to the discrete time case, could someone provide me some reference for the continuous-time case? Thanks very much!

Comment: I'm not sure if for the continuous-time positive Harris Markov process, the theorem with proof also holds true. When we consider a coupling method in the continuous-time, there can be situation that 2 processes meet with probability 0, there can be an atom...?